# KeyEvent.VK_MINUS interpreted as German 'ß' by Java Robot

Tags: java, macos, awtrobot

The following code will result in typing a 'ß' instead of a '-' on MAC OSX 10.10 with Java 7. Any ideas about how to solve this are welcome.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            String cmd = "open /Applications/TextEdit.app";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            Robot robot = new Robot();

            robot.delay(2000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS);

        } catch (AWTException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the keyboard layout is changed to US before running this code?

Comment: Try using `VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK` . I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clearly spelled out, but [the Javadoc for the `keyPress` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#keyPress-int-) is phrased in terms of "keycodes", which normally means that it's mapping to *a specific physical key* on the keyboard, which the operating system then interprets as some key event (such as "hyphen" or "double S").

[The standard German layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTZ) has the double S on the key two left of the backspace, which is the hyphen/minus on a QWERTY keyboard.

As for how to solve this, you apparently need to be aware of the keyboard layout. There's [a library called Window Licker](https://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/) that's supposed to handle layout issues with the Robot.